# how to get JVM INSTR tableswitch into the code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arraylist, jvm

A syntax error is occuring in "goto", and another error (_L cannot be resolved to a variable). I want to keep the "goto", but HOW to correct the code ?

The code:

```
public static ArrayList getTemplateList(Context context) {
    XArraySharedObject xarraysharedobject = getArraySharedObject(context);
    if (xarraysharedobject.size() != 0) {
        goto _L2; 
    } else {
        goto _L1
    }

    _L1:
        int i = 0;
    _L5:
        if (i < DEFAULT_TEMPLATES.length) goto _L3; else goto _L2
    _L2:
        return xarraysharedobject.getArrayList();
    _L3:
        xarraysharedobject.add(DEFAULT_TEMPLATES[i]);
        i++;
        if (true) goto _L5; else goto _L4
    _L4:
}
```

Comment: What gives you the idea that you can use "goto" in Java code?

Comment: Get a better decompiler. Or learn what bytecode operations actually mean. This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Realistically, you have some kind of for, do, or while loop here.  Staring at the code for a few minutes will reveal which.  Once you sort that out the rest of the _L# fragments can be slotted in inline.

Answer (score 0):

GOTO is object orientated development's arch nemesis and has no place in Java code. You should instead create methods to call in each case OR use a

```
  switch (thing to check) {
       case 1:
           //do action 1
           break;
       case 2:
           //do action 2
           break;
  }
```

You should spend some time doing [Android](http://developer.android.com/index.html) tutorials and/or learning the language if you're new to it - [Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)